# UBUNTU 15.10 & UBUNTU 15.10 SERVER QUESTION

Tags: server, 15.10

Hi i wanted to know if the 2 are different or are they the same? If different can any1 shed some light and what are they used for? I Use UBUNTU 15.10 and was interested on installing "LAMP". I use my Ubuntu PC for everyday use of simple tasks like web browsing etc.. but i also am learning to code/software & app dev.. if Ubuntu 15.10 OS Different from Ubuntu 15.10 SERVER, would it the same or does the fact it has "Server" make my PC act different? or better yet what does it mean by server and what does server do or used for?
Thank you..

Answer (score -4):

Ubuntu Server is for servers, and is not recommended for normal use. It has a terminal interface, probably something newbies should not use.

Ubuntu Desktop is for normal use, and newbies can use this like freedom.

Comment: Don't put someone down by calling them a newbie. The OP is asking for advice and you tell him "You're a newbie so don't even think about it. NEWBIE!"...